# how to improve the code efficiency of "deleting all 'newline' except last one in one string"?

Tags: erlang

I want to filter log data by cleaning all new line character in every log message. The following is my code, but it seems low efficient, how to improve it?

```
character_drop_test_b()->
    List = "AB\nC\nD\n",
    Result = re:replace(List, "[\n]", "", [global, {return, list}]) ++ "\n",
    Result.
```

Comment: What makes you think it is "low efficient" ? Despite a common believe, basic RE are fast. It is compiling the regex that could be time consuming. But you could [compile](http://erlang.org/doc/man/re.html#compile-1) it ahead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you're replacing a fixed string rather than a pattern, you don't need to use regular expressions. Try this instead:

```
string:join(string:tokens(List, "\n"), "") ++ "\n"
```

By my measurements it's 3x faster than your approach on your small `List` and 6x faster than your approach for a list composed of 1000 copies of the `List` data.